# Неубиваемый сервис убивается

Tags: android, service, android-service

Проблема такого рода, что неубиваемый сервис все равно убивается системой.
Суть сервиса - GPS-трекер, который постоянно должен отсылать данные серверу.
На эмуляторе работает нормально, на устройствах постоянно падает и не возобновляется. На своем устройстве (Lenovo S820) пробовал убивать процесс чистильщиками и вручную выгружать из списка работающих приложений. Оба варианта приводят к завершению без последующего восстановления. При переводе телефона в спящий режим результат аналогичный.

Что сделано для неубиваемости:

выставил перезапуск сервиса после его закрытия:

```
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
{
    ......

    return START_STICKY;
}
```

добавил уведомление foreground:

```
public void onCreate()
{
    .......

        this.makeForegroundNotification();

    .......

}

public void makeForegroundNotification()
{
    if (mNotificationManager == null)
    {
         mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    }
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 1, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
    builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
        .setTicker(getString(R.string.georequest_foreground_ticker))
        .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.georequest_foreground_title))
        .setContentText(getString(R.string.georequest_foreground_text))
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_gris_notif)
        .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_gris_logo))
        .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX);
    Notification notification = builder.build();
    notification.flags |=Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR;

    startForeground(FOREGROUND_NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
}
```

добавил `AlarmManager` в `onCreate()` сервиса:

```
    AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent receiverIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CheckServiceReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 3,
            receiverIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    manager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, 5000, (60*1000), pendingIntent);
```

Также добавил сервис в автозапуск.

На своем устройстве при выгрузке сервиса пропадает и `AlarmManager` (для проверки прописал в нем вывод `Toast` при каждом срабатывании). Падение сервиса в спящем режиме не происходит, если остается запущенной активность этого приложения.

Answer (score 2):

Покапай вот в эту сторону:

```
PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE);
WakeLock wakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK,
        "MyWakelockTag");
wakeLock.acquire();
```

http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/training/scheduling/wakelock.html

Я так делал неусыпляемый сервис для опроса GPS

Comment: Попробовал, но никакого эффекта

Comment: Тогда в try catch заверни весь код и анализируй, что внутри происходит. Андройд - дело тонкое )

Comment: Завернуто. Причем catch ошибку выводит в логи и сохраняет в preference для большего контроля. Нигде ничего (